# Chrome and Opera browsers not loading CSS and JavaScript files (404 - Not Found)

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, wildfly

I'm facing a strange problem.

Technologies I'm using:

- Java 11
- Wildfly 20
- Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0)

The problem is that when I open a page of the application I'm developing on Chrome or Opera browsers, the css and JavaScript files are not applied, the browser don't load them as if they were forbidden. If I open in any other browser (Firefox, Microsoft Edge, ...), the page loads normally, with css and JavaScript applied.

In *Chrome* or *Opera* browsers (no css):

[image]

In *Firefox* or *Microsoft Edge* browsers (with css):

[image]

Inspection in Chrome:

[image]

[image]

These are the relevant parts of some files:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>restricted</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>USUARIO</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>allowed</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/templates/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>USUARIO</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>NAO_AUTORIZADO</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>inicio.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**jboss-app.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-app>
    <security-domain>jaspitest</security-domain>
</jboss-app>
```

**AutenticadorUsuario.java**

```
@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
    loginToContinue = @LoginToContinue(
        loginPage = "/login.xhtml",
        errorPage = ""
    )
)
@FacesConfig
@ApplicationScoped
public class AutenticadorUsuario implements IdentityStore
```

**Page source code in browser:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
        <title>Autenticação</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link href="resources/css/autenticacao.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/script/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/script/autenticacao.js"></script>
        <link href="resources/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/script/login.js"></script></head><body>
        <header>
        </header>

        <main>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/autenticacao/login.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form" />

                <div id="titulo">
        Login

                </div>

                <div id="conteudo">
        <div id="campos"><label for="form:nomeUsuario">Nome do usuário:</label><input id="form:nomeUsuario" type="text" name="form:nomeUsuario" /><label for="form:senha">Senha:</label><input id="form:senha" type="password" name="form:senha" value="" /><input type="submit" name="form:j_idt18" value="Entrar" />
        </div>
                </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-1019286018880157796:-2226995668037289798" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
        </main>

        <footer>
            <p> </p>
        </footer></body>
</html>
```

**Project structure**

[image]

I already did a clean build, clean deploy, clear browser caches, disabled antivirus and firewall. The problem remains.

**IF I DISABLE SECURITY IN MY APPLICATION (in web.xml), THE PROBLEM IS GONE (I've already checked this). So it seems that this is related to security**,

but I need security enabled in this application.

If I view the source code on browser and click on the css or JavaScript files, I get

**404 - Not Found**

Since I posted this question, I upgraded to Wildfly 20 to see if it was a bug in Wildfly 19 that was corrected, but it was not.

This application is no different from other applications I developed using previous versions of JBoss or Wildfly. The new thing is that I'm using Custom FORM authentication instead of FORM authentication. I'm also using the new Java EE Security.

What's going on here?

**UPDATE 1:**

Hey, look at what *Chrome* and *Opera* are doing. The correct resources url is this:

**http://localhost:8080/autenticacao/resources/css/autenticacao.css**

but when security is enabled, *Chrome* and *Opera* change the url to this:

**http://localhost:8080/resources/css/autenticacao.css**

Sure the resource is not in this last url.

Any ideas why they are doing this?

**UPDATE 2:**

I've found the problem. Look at the answer below.

Comment: I removed to the java tag (you cannot reproduce in a plain jdk), eclipse is not related since it is an ide and it works for other browsers and jakarta-ee is to broad and added the chrome tag since it only fails in that. And did you check the chrome developertools? http errors? Other errors? CSS (partly) invalid which one browser acts worse upon than others? Tried in a very simple war without authentication? Tried this simple war on Tomcat? Browser plugins messing things up? etc... Narrow things down

Comment: Without authentication it works, but the application has to have authentication. Not only css files don't load, JavaScript files also don't load.

Comment: This security is not JSF related... Sure only the css is not loaded? Not by accident a cached page shown in Chrome! Or the other way around, FF has cached CSS from before authentication? But if it is authentication related, it is very strange that only chrome suffers and then you have 403 or 401's Bad investigation... Please investigate more.

Comment: _"Sure only the css is not loaded?"_. Not only css, but all other files referenced on the html page. If I view the source code on browser and click on the css or JavaScript files, I get 404 - Not Found. As I said, very strange problem, have never happened before with me.

Comment: 404 is not authentication (401) or authorization (403) related... And there are more questions in my previous comment. Do a clean build, clean deploy, clear browser caches. Maybe the 'normal page' is retrieved from cache

Comment: _"Do a clean build, clean deploy, clear browser caches"_. All done. Same thing.

Comment: If you hover over the downvote arrow, you see a tooltip with info. In this case it might be a combination of inconsistencies between text and comment _"as if they were forbidden"_ vs the comment of 404. 404 is not authentication, Spo effectively your question is unclear. Lots of things you can (and **should**) investigate between browsers. Client and server side. And only now after asking there is more info. Still not enough, since it is authentication related, there should be 403/401's and if it works without authentication, check if the requested urls are the same etc...

Comment: Updated the question: noticed the problem also happens in Opera browser, not only Chrome. Firefox and Microsoft Edge works ok.

Comment: Will I have to use a filter and implement user authentication manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I changed the application URL in the browser from this:

http://localhost:8080/autenticacao

to this:

http://localhost:8080/autenticacao/

and it worked, the resources were found.